# which Data Type using SQL Server 2008 for HASH VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hash, types

I need to save HASH VALUE in SQL Server 2008.
Does i need some specific DataType to select?
Which one can I use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CHAR is fine for hash values.

Comment: +1. Especially as it is READABLE. YO could use binary, but i find the advantage of being able to read the value big enough to jsutify the really tiny size / perforamcne loss.

Comment: how long should be char value? as default in SQL Server 2008 it is char(10)

Comment: As long as your hash in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type is the hash. Is it SQL Server native hash or custom generated?

From [Hash functions in SQL](http://blogs.clarience.com/davide/?p=11)

> SQL Server has the CHECKSUM() (and
>   BINARY_CHECKSUM()) function for
>   generating hash values. This is a
>   simple hash function that maps input
>   value(s) to a 32-bit INTEGER value.
>   CHECKSUM() and BINARY_CHECKSUM()
>   differ in how they treat inputs of the
>   string data-type; see the
>   BINARY_CHECKSUM() topic in BOL for
>   more information.